# Foreign Key Error on MySQL CREATE TABLE statement (err: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-error-1005

I feel I've tried everything possible on a very simple pair of create table statements.

The types match, I tried using ENGINE = InnoDB, etc and am stumped why I'm getting the foreign key error.

I've been away from SQL for some time, so this is probably an easy one.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo_ent(yyy_no VARCHAR(80),
    -> zoo VARCHAR(80),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (yyy_no));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE cat_ent(some_item INTEGER,
    -> yyy_no VARCHAR(80),
    -> apple DECIMAL(6,2),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (some_item),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (yyy_no) REFERENCES foo_ent);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.cat_ent' (errno: 15
0)
```

Sorry about the poor variable names, safe to over-write company stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reference to a field, only a table, which is incorrect.

```
...
foreign key (yyy_no) references foo_ent(yyy_no)
```

And according to your error number, the MySQL documentation also states;

> If you re-create a table that was
>   dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key
>   constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types,
>   and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If
>   these are not satisfied, MySQL returns
>   error number 1005 and refers to error
>   150 in the error message.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Ah, I thought at one time you only had to specify the field of the table when the field names were different between the two.  Maybe they changed this or I am incorrect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the name of the referenced column explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE cat_ent
        (
        some_item INTEGER NOT NULL,
        yyy_non VARCHAR(80),
        apple DECIMAL(6,2),
        PRIMARY KEY (some_item),
        FOREIGN KEY (yyy_non) REFERENCES foo_ent(yyy_no)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider rewriting your FOREIGN KEY declaration to explicitly list the column in foo_ent that you want to key on:

CREATE TABLE cat_ent(some_item INTEGER,
     yyy_no VARCHAR(80),
     apple DECIMAL(6,2),
     PRIMARY KEY (some_item),
     FOREIGN KEY (yyy_no) REFERENCES foo_ent(yyy_no))
ENGINE=InnoDB;

works for me.