# Can't create table with foreign key - MySQL Error 150

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble understanding why I'm getting MySQL code error 150 for the following snippet:

```
-- Exercise Categories
CREATE TABLE Exercise_cat
(
ec_id       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name        VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (ec_id)
);
-- This inserts fine

-- Exercise Descriptions
CREATE TABLE Exercise_desc
(
e_id        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name        VARCHAR(25),
ec_id       INT NOT NULL,
cal_per_hour    INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (e_id),
FOREIGN KEY (ec_id) REFERENCES Excercise_cat(ec_id)
);
-- ERROR (foreign key constraint not formed)
```

I didn't leave off the column name, as in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357936/foreign-key-error-on-mysql-create-table-statement-err-150)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236668/foreign-keys-in-mysql).
I have semicolons, as MySQL wants me to.

How would I fix my foreign key so that I can create the table?

Comment: Is that a typo on your foreign key? table Excercise_cat does not exist - shouldn't it be Exercise_cat?

Comment: I'm looking at [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip241028/i02create.xml) and wondering why their example works for me. The biggest difference I see is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but I don't know if that's material.

Comment: You are right matthewh! I feel a little silly. Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you are referencing **`Excercise_cat` does not exists**. But **Exercise_cat exists.**

So the following line should be corrected.

```
FOREIGN KEY (ec_id) REFERENCES Excercise_cat(ec_id)
                                 ^
                                 |
                                 +-- Remove this extra 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean `Exercise_cat` not `Excercise_cat`

```
CREATE TABLE Exercise_desc
(
    e_id        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(25),
    ec_id       INT NOT NULL,
    cal_per_hour    INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (e_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ec_id) REFERENCES Exercise_cat(ec_id)
);
```